# How to transfer files bertween two nodejs servers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, file-transfer

I'am trying to create a server that can host files. This server chould run on a normal computer with windows, and i shold be able to transfer his files to another computer.

I alredy can transfer files that are text based: .txt, .html, .js, but doesnt work to transfer images: .png, .jpg

I tryed with fs.readFile and fs.load but the result is the same.

**server.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

var port = process.argv[2];

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  console.log('new connection');

  request.on('data',(data)=>{
    let c = JSON.parse(data);

    switch(c.todo[3]){

      case 'downFile':
        if(c.todo[4]&&c.todo[5]){

          let src = c.todo[4];

          let readStream = fs.createReadStream(src);
          readStream.once('error',(err)=>{
            console.log(err);
            response.write(JSON.stringify(err));
            response.end();
          });
          //console.log(readStream);

          readStream.once('end',()=>{
            console.log('copy done');
            response.end();
          });

          readStream.pipe(response);

        }else{
          response.write(JSON.stringify('Need to specify the name of the file'));
          response.end();
        }
        break;

      default:
        //console.log('chexk');
        response.write(JSON.stringify('Unknown command'));
        response.end();
        break;
    }

      // response.write('success');

  })

}).listen(port);

console.log('App Running');
```

**client.js**

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var port = process.argv[2];
var path = process.argv[3];

var data = {
  json:{
    todo: process.argv
  }
}

var url = 'http://localhost:'+port;
request.post(url,data,(err,res,body)=>{
  if(err)console.log(err)
  else{
    fs.writeFile(process.argv[5]+process.argv[4],body,(err)=>{
      if(err)console.log(err);
    })
  }
})
```

To start the server I use:
node server.js port
and to make the tranfer i use:
node client.js port downFile inputPath outputPath
Sorry about the english :/

Comment: what is your main question?, **but doesnt work to transfer images: .png, .jpg?**

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation for the discrepancy between text and non-text file transfers is the `Content-Type` header of the resource. Especially because you are creating a lower-level server through `http` rather than a higher-level service like `express`, you need to be careful to set an appropriate `Content-Type` for the content being transferred. You can likely extrapolate based off of file extension.

For more information on the HTTP `Content-Type` header, check out the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)